# Return ID of the field after comparing values of a different column

Tags: c#, mysql, database, linq, linq-to-sql

I need to `return` the `ID` of the person (employee), depending on the `username` which is written in a `toolstripstatuslabel`. 
My logic is to get the `username` from the `textbox`, check the `database` `table`, and then `return` the `ID` of the found username. 
However I do not know how to return the `PersonID`, can anyone kindly help as the research I found was `returning` value of an `inserted` `table` and not my case.

Business Logic Code:

```
public List<Person> getEmployeeByID(string empName)
{
    LinqToSqlDataContext database = new LinqToSqlDataContext();
    return database.Persons.Where(emp => emp.personName.Contains(empName)).ToList();
    //return the ID of the person which carries the textbox's name
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: is `empName` unique in persons table?

Answer (score 1):

If there is more than one person it should be like this:

```
public List<String> getEmployeeByID(string empName)
{
    LinqToSqlDataContext database = new LinqToSqlDataContext();
    return database.Persons.Where(emp => emp.personName.Contains(empName)).Select(c => c.ID).ToList();
}
```

Or if you want to return just one person you can use [`FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb340482(v=vs.100).aspx) or [`SingleOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb342451(v=vs.100).aspx). For example:

```
public String getEmployeeByID(string empName)
{
    LinqToSqlDataContext database = new LinqToSqlDataContext();
    return database.Persons.FirsOrDefault(emp => emp.personName.Contains(empName)).ID;
}
```

Also be careful to change the return types of your method to `List<String>` or `String` based on your needs. (I assumed that your `ID` is of type `String`)

Comment: I have used the method with `int`, as `personID` is of type `int`. 

Now I need to show it from the `form`, I can't figure out how I can apply the method to a `textbox` as an error is popped.
`Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'`. I tried to `parse` but still nothing worked. Sorry for asking alot but I'm quite new to this. Thanks again!

`frm.tsslMenu.Text = emp.getEmployeeByID(usernameTxt.Text);`

Comment: @hurkaperpa...So change the method's return type to `int` or `List<int>`.

Comment: @hurkaperpa...After changing your method's return type to `int` like this:`public int getEmployeeByID(string empName)
{
    LinqToSqlDataContext database = new LinqToSqlDataContext();
    return database.Persons.FirsOrDefault(emp => emp.personName.Contains(empName)).ID;
}` to call it do like this:`frm.tsslMenu.Text = emp.getEmployeeByID(usernameTxt.Text).ToString();`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming empName is a unique user name, you can write:

```
public int getEmployeeID(string empName)
{
    LinqToSqlDataContext database = new LinqToSqlDataContext();
    return database.Persons
       .Where(emp => emp.personName.Contains(empName))
       .Single().Id;
    //return the ID of the person which carries the textbox's name
}
```

If it is possible that empName will not match any record in the database, you can check for that possibility. Here I return null if there is no match and make use of a new C#6 syntax feature to avoid separately checking if SingleOrDefault() returned null. Note this will throw an exception if there are multiple matches, which is most likely what you want. FirstOrDefault() will silently ignore additional rows with the same (supposedly unique) user name.

```
public int? getEmployeeID(string empName)
{
    LinqToSqlDataContext database = new LinqToSqlDataContext();
    return database.Persons
       .Where(emp => emp.personName.Contains(empName))
       .SingleOrDefault()?.Id;
    //return the ID of the person which carries the textbox's name
}
```